# LINQ Expression can not be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I used the following calculation to calculated `DaysPastDue`. The calculation is working fine, I get the right result but when I filter record by `DaysPastDue`  I get `could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()`

```
var billing= _context.Billing.AsNoTracking()
.Select(i => new BillingSearchDTO
{
   ID = i.ID,
   InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber,
   DaysPastDue = i.InvoiceDetail.Where(i => 
                 i.TypeID == TypeID_XT ||
                 i.TypeID == TypeID_XP)
                  .Select(i=> i.AmountRemaining)
                  .Sum() > 0 ? DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Invoicedate.AddDays(i.ProductNav.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault())).Days : 0,.Days : 0
});
```

The calculation is working fine I get the right result but when filtering grid by `DaysPastDue` for some reason I keep getting the following error

> Select(i2 => i2.AmountRemaining)
> .Sum() > 0 ? DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Outer.Invoicedate.AddDays((double)i.Inner.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault())).Days : 0 == 656)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at ...

Any Help?

Comment: Split your query into an anonymous type with the `.Sum()`, `i.Invoicedate` etc, which you run as sql. Then do the date calc client side.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLakeman, can you explain me how?

Comment: "by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()". eg `(await ....Select(i => new { ... }).ToListAsync()).Select(i => new BillingSearchDTO{ ... })`.

Comment: thank you @JeremyLakeman but no luck. may be i miss something

Comment: Use `EF.Functions.DateDiffDay` and others. EF is bad in translating DateTime queries.